# Customize Ckeditor plug-in into Domino 8.5.3

Tags: xpages

I I have read this url
[first official](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/CKEditor_in_XPages_in_NotesDomino_8.5.2)

and this [another blog](http://www.intec.co.uk/xpages-8-5-2-rich-text-extending-the-ckeditor/)

But they only describe how the toolbar parameter 'Large', 'Medium' etc. work.

How can I hide, for example, the plug-in "Full-Screen" or enable the native plug-in of Ckeditor 3.X named "spell-check"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You link to two articles that both mention that you can configure the CKEditor with exactly the buttons you want.

From http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/CKEditor_in_XPages_in_NotesDomino_8.5.2:

> To define your own toolbar, add a Dojo attribute to the Rich Text Control called toolbar. Compute the value for this attribute in Server Side JavaScript and enter an array containing the toolbar options you want to make available.

```
var myToolbar = "[['Font','FontSize'], \n"
        +"['Preview', 'Bold','TextColor','BGColor'], \n"
        +"['Italic','Underline','Strike','-','Subscript','Superscript']]";
return myToolbar;
```

Comment: Ehmmm tnx you.
But IBM don't have the native plug-in SpellCheck of CkEditor...
I see into config.js

config.lotusSpellChecker = {
  restUrl:'',
  lang:'en',
  suggestions:'5',
  format:'json',
  highlight: { element : 'span', styles : { 'background-color' : 'yellow', 'color' : 'black' } },
        preventCache: true
 };

Anyone have idea?