# Customize CKEditor under XPages (the right way)

Tags: ckeditor, xpages

I need to customize CKEditor's toolbar with custom buttons sets.

I have already read these questions/answers and linked ressources:

- [Customize Ckeditor plug-in into Domino 8.5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030295/customize-ckeditor-plug-in-into-domino-8-5-3)
- [How to configure the CKEditor under XPages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083997/how-to-configure-the-ckeditor-under-xpages)

What they do works, if you always do a full page refresh. But if you do a partial refresh of a part of the page - including at least one rich text control (CKEditor version 4.3.2) - **after** the **partial refresh** CKEditor chooses a toolbar like **'Full'** (I don't really know, but I think the default type) as toolbar type to display.

The problem is the whole *dojo-widget - custom IBM CKEditor - thing*. It makes your `toolbar` dojo property being 'forgotten/ignored' after a partial refresh (but it is still set!!!).

Anyone having experience/knowledge, how to solve this best, e.g. the IBM way (if there is any?!?!?)?

I solved it quick and dirty by changing properties of the global CKEditor JS variable (executed every time inside the partial refresh block):

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock2">
    <xp:this.value>
        <![CDATA[
            CKEDITOR.config.readOnly = true;
            CKEDITOR.config.removePlugins = 'autogrow';
            CKEDITOR.config.autoGrow_minHeight = 250;
            CKEDITOR.config.autoGrow_maxHeight = 250;
            CKEDITOR.config.toolbarLocation = 'top';

            CKEDITOR.config.toolbar_readonly = [
                { name: 'tools', items: ['Find','Print', 'Preview', 'Maximize']}
            ];
        ]]>
    </xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

#### System:

- IBM Domino 9.0.1 FP2 (local on client PC)
- OpenNTF Domino Framework in use
- Windows 7 32 bit

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but here's an approach that works:

The CK Editor uses a configuration file. By default it is this file: `domino/html/ckeditor/config.js`. It holds all the settings for the editor, including the toolbar. If you override that file by providing your own version (copy it from the original) and configuring the toolbar in your own version, that configuration will always be used, even when doing a partial refresh.

To make the CK Editor use your custom config file you need to add a dojo attribute to the `xp:inputRichText` control:

```
<xp:dojoAttribute
    name="customConfig"
    value="yourConfigFile.js">
</xp:dojoAttribute>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional capabilities to your CK Editor using:

```
 <xp:inputRichText id="inputRichText1">
    <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
        <xp:dojoAttribute name="extraPlugins" value="mustache">
        </xp:dojoAttribute>      
    </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
 </xp:inputRichText>
```

and in JavaScript you add:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'mustache', ...);
```

The full stories is in 2 parts on my blog [here](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-9HZ2EA) and [here - Part 2](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-9J3BJ3)

Let us know how it goes!

Comment: Thanks. Very interesting read on your blog. But that is not what I am looking for. I don't need a plugin like i.e. spellchecking or whatever. I just want to configure the toolbar to show  a set of existing buttons

Comment: Same mechanism. You have 2 options: amend the toolbar (like in my blog) or replace it. Usually you only find replacement instructions

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dojo.behavior` to run a JavaScript function on page load and after each partial refresh. Here's an example of it in use, although this example is to add a FontAwesome image to categories on a DataView http://www.intec.co.uk/getting-awesome-category-icons-in-data-views/