# xp:inputRichText - Get rid of "Press ALT 0 for help"?

Tags: xpages

The standard control `<xp:inputRichText>` is nice. However I really don't like the "Press ALT 0 for help" label that shows up at the bottom right.

Is there any way to get rid of it ?

Answer (score 1):

That text is in a ckeditor plugin named 'ibmstatusmessage'.  It's recommended to keep it for accessibility (to help blind users navigate).

But you could try modifying the ckeditor toolbar to a new configuration that doesn't have that plugin. There are other discussions on adding to the toolbar, e.g. [Customize CKEditor under XPages (the right way)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26994035/customize-ckeditor-under-xpages-the-right-way) but I don't know offhand how to remove from it.